# Stop countdown when it reaches to "0"

Tags: javascript

I want to stop this counter when it reaches to 0, can anyone help me?

```
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
```

Comment: Worst answer of the day: wrap `i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;` in an `else` block. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html >
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="counter">5</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)==0) {
       clearInterval(timerId);
    }
}
var timerId = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You use the clearInterval function:

```
var id;
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=1) {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
id = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

Comment: I would just suggest to change `setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);` to `setInterval(countdown,1000);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="counter">10</div>

var i = document.getElementById('counter'),
    sId;

function countdown() {
    var count = parseInt(i.textContent, 10);

    if (count < 1) {
        clearInterval(id);
    }

    i.textContent = count - 1;
}

sId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/N5eDF/)

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine on jsfiddle, but why it dosen't work on my .js file?

Comment: Impossible for me to answer that without all the information, or even a description of what is not happening, or errors, etc etc

Comment: You right, here is from error console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Comment: Then the div with the id of "counter" was not found on your page. For example, take the answer you accepted and replace the javascript with the above or the other you could not get to work and all will most likely be fine.

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
function countdown() {
  var el = document.getElementById('counter');
  var value = parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10);

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    el.innerHTML = --value;
    if (value === 0) {
       clearInterval(intervalId);      
    }
  }, 1000);
};

countdown();
```

Comment: It works too on jsfiddle, but didn't work on my site. what's the problem?